# Authenticate scripts on HDFS using key.tab file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, kerberos, keytab

How to authenticate scripts on hadoop hdfs  in a kerberos environment using key-tab file. we get GSS authentication error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kinit -kt `whoami`.keytab `whoami`@INTRANET.SERVER.COM
```

placing the key-tab file in hdfs user home folder and adding above in start of all scripts worked for me.